# How to resize a UITextView according to the content, with fixed width

Tags: ios

I have to create a UITextView programmatically, but I ran into some trouble about setting its size.

Suppose I have a sentence, with multiple lines:

> s = @"Hello World\nHello World\nHello World\n";

Now I want to figure out the height I need to display it, and set my UITextView's height accordingly (the width need to be fixed). Following is my code:

```
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:_FONT_MYRIADPRO(20.0f) constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 1000)];
    
    _textBox.text = text;
    _textBox.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, size.height);
    _textBox.font = _FONT_MYRIADPRO(20.0f);
    _textBox.textColor = _COLOR_BLACK;
    _textBox.backgroundColor = _COLOR_BLUE_DARK;

    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, _textBox.frame.size.height + 2 * 10);

     [self addSubview:_textBox];
```

However, the result is like:

[image]

I have tried many other methods, like call

```
[_textBox sizeToFit]
```

which also fails, because I want to fix width.

I also tried

```
    NSAttributedString *titleText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: _FONT_MYRIADPRO(20.0f)}];
    CGRect bound = [titleText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(300, 1000) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
        
    _textBox.text = text;
    _textBox.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, bound.size.height);
```

it also fails, and result is the same as the above image.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: now you only want to fix width according to the string length?

Comment: have you try to fix the width after you use sizeToFit?

Comment: @Chancy I want to load the text dynamically, maintain the UITextView's width fixed. Thus I need to adjust the height of it according to the text being loaded

Comment: why sizeToFit is not suitable to u?

Comment: now the height is right? only the width is not correct for u?

Comment: @Chancy, because, for example, I want to "Hello World" to be in the same line(and indeed there is not \n between them), but using sizeToFit may cause "World" to change to the next line, and the whole bounding rectangle has a smaller width.

Comment: @Chancy, the height is not right, it may contain unwanted line-changing.

Comment: maybe you can use [@"your string" sizeWithFont:yourFont] to calculate the size and then do some adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

I do some test for this case.  I think we'd better add descender and leading for height.  Please refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html for the details of the meanings of descender and leading.

My sample code is as below:

```
//
//  RootViewController.m
//  TextViewSize
//
//  Created by AnkyHe on 11/13/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Gery Studio. All rights reserved.
//
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#import "RootViewController.h"

#define TextFont ([UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0f])

static NSString *textContent = nil;
static NSUInteger const LineNum = 10;

@interface RootViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak)  UITextView *textView;

@end

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSMutableArray *lines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:LineNum];
    for (int i = 0; i < LineNum; ++i) {
        [lines addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Hello world", i]];
    }

    textContent = [lines componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    self.textView = textView;
    self.textView.text = textContent;
    self.textView.font = TextFont;
    [self.view addSubview:self.textView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    CGRect textRect = [textContent boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(300, 1000)
                                                options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                             attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:TextFont}
                                                context:nil];

    CGSize size = textRect.size;
    self.textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, size.height + TextFont.descender + TextFont.leading);
    self.textView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds));
}

@end
```

The output is as below:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried other text? Like 10 lines of "Hello World"? It seems the problem is still there. My original method works fine with UILabel, and now I find that in UITextView, after each line, there will be an extra 4pt, which is not calculated by the method of NSString like [boundingRectWithSize]...Do you know what this extra 4pt is?

Comment: I test 10 lines and it is OK still.  Please read my revised code.